# Dealing with universal-ctags, python builtins and poetry

Tags: python, vim, ctags, universal-ctags

I'm using universal-ctags to navigate among objects define in my projects and it works perfectly fines. However i'm struggling to find how to include python builtins objects and package dependencies into the scope of universal-ctags. On the top of it, i'm using poetry (not my choice), which locate dependencies elsewhere than in the directory of my project. (if my project is `.`, the related python dependencies are `../../../.cache/pypoetry/....`)

Say otherwise, i would like that <C-]> on works on every case whenever i'm targetting custom python object, python builtin (`join`, `choice`, `lru_cache`, etc...), dependencie object (`Model` from Django, `ViewSet` from DRF, etc...)

Is there any way to specifie to universal-ctags to fetch all of those additionnal references ?

Thanks !

I thought an option exists to add path to include additionnal to look at, but i did not found anything  about that.

I'm using universal-ctags, vim and on Debian 11

Comment: Well, you are supposed to point `ctags` to what you want to index so you would do `$ ctags -R . ../../../.cache/pypoetry /some/path /some/other/path`, which will put all the found tags in the same `tags` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can stitch together a one-liner to do this for you.

As [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) commented, you can pass several paths to generate a single tags file from. And that's pretty much the answer. We can add some fluff, though.

The Python standard library modules will be found in `sys.path`, e.g. `/usr/lib/python3.9` on my Debian box. I assume this to change rarely (only when you upgrade your Python installation). It does not seem worthwhile to automate this.

Poetry's virtualenv is more volatile, so the path should be found automatically. According to the information in [this poetry issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/106), you can get the virtualenv's path (and some more output we don't care about) with `poetry show -v`.

Putting it together with a little Bash glue, we get the following one-liner:

```bash
ctags -R . /usr/lib/python3.9 $(poetry show -v | head -n1 | cut -d':' -f2)
```

Or - shamelessly stealing the more concise way of getting the path from [Gwildor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7242343/gwildor)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77786069/796259) - this one-liner becomes even more awesome:

```bash
ctags -R . /usr/lib/python3.9 $(poetry env info --path)
```

You may want to turn this into a shell script or function and append `"$@"` to pass additional options.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Friedrich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76236349/796259), there is a way in Poetry to get the path to the virtual environment directly, using `poetry env info --path`. So the command then becomes:

```
ctags -R . $(poetry env info --path)
```

I don't think it's necessary to add the Python interpreter as well, as that is also part of the Poetry virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaws in my answer. Not sure if we could just omit the system packages, though. There's a lot of stuff in there not found in the venv. I don't think I'm familiar enough with how venvs work to give a definitive answer.

Comment: ...and I hope you don't mind me editing your much improved poetry call into my answer.